# Control get automatically transfered from one textbox to other textbox?

Tags: textbox, html

My webpage contains two textboxes. By default the page focus is on first textbox. When I type the third character in the first textbox, I want the control to get automatically transfered to second textbox. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is really easy using jQuery's keyUp() function.

An example of your HTML would be helpful though so we can see the easiest way of hooking the JS in. What JS framework (if any) do you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ThirdCharPressed(){
 var char=1;
 $('#yourtextbox').keypress(function()
 char++;
 if(char==3)
 $('#yourSecondtextbox').foucus();
 });
}
```

This may work i guess

Comment: which event should use this? Onkeypress() event?

Comment: you can use it onKeypress event yes